# How to extract numerator from fraction in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fraction like 15/3 stored in **varchar**. I want to extract numerator(15) in sql server. How can i do it?

Comment: `substring` and `charindex` will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @str varchar(max) = '15/3'

select left(@str, charindex('/', @str)-1)
```

[**`CHARINDEX`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) locates the index of `/` character, `LEFT` uses this index in order to extract the numerator.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/UBD66133)

Comment: Thanks. I was also trying this but did not use -1 in charindex.